# Stubbed object method value not returned in Spock test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, spock, stubbing

I am new to the Spock framework and writing a test case in which I am trying to Mock a class called QueryDatabase

```
public class QueryDatabase {

    public BigInteger countRecords(Instant start, Instant end) {

        Flux<CountRecord> countValue = query("select * from users");
        Optional<Object> value = Optional.ofNullable(countValue.blockFirst()).map(CountRecord::getValue);
        BigInteger count = value.filter(BigInteger.class::isInstance)
                    .map(BigInteger.class::cast).orElse(BigInteger.valueOf(0));

        return count
    }
    
    public Flux<CountRecord> query(String query) {
    
    }
}
```

but the below test case which is to check the value returned by countRecords(Instant, Instant) always gives 0, so that means the value returned in the ***when*** section

```
recordCount.query(_) >> Flux.just(CountRecord.builder().value(new BigInteger(133)).build())
```

is not getting used, seems like `recordCount.query(_) >> Flux.empty()` also does not have any impact and it always returns the default BigInteger value 0

```
def "record count"() {

        given:
        def now = Instant.now()
        def last10Minutes = now.minus(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        def recordCount = Stub(QueryDatabase)

        when: "query returning empty flux"
        recordCount.query(_) >> Flux.empty()

        then:
        recordCount.countRecords(last10Minutes, now) == 0

        when: "query returning the count record"
        recordCount.query(_) >> Flux.just(CountRecord.builder().value(new BigInteger(133)).build())

        then:
        recordCount.countRecords(last10Minutes, now) == 133

 }
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. You try to set up some stubbing in the `when` block
2. You perform your action in the `then` block
3. You try to redefine stubs

See [Combining Mocking and Stubbing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing) on how this works.

```
def "record count"() {    
        given:
        def now = Instant.now()
        def last10Minutes = now.minus(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        def recordCount = Spy(QueryDatabase)

        when: "query returning empty flux"
        def result = recordCount.countRecords(last10Minutes, now)

        then:            
        1 * recordCount.query(_) >> Flux.empty()
        result == 0

        when: "query returning the count record"
        def 2ndResult = recordCount.countRecords(last10Minutes, now) == 133

        then:            
        1 * recordCount.query(_) >> Flux.just(CountRecord.builder().value(new BigInteger(133)).build())
        2ndResult == 133    
 }
```

Alternatively, you could split it up into a data driven feature

```
def "record count"(BigInteger result, Flux input) {    
        given:
        def now = Instant.now()
        def last10Minutes = now.minus(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        def recordCount = Spy(QueryDatabase)
        recordCount.query(_) >> input

        expect:          
        recordCount.countRecords(last10Minutes, now) == result

        where: 
        result | input
        0      | Flux.empty()
        133    | Flux.just(CountRecord.builder().value(new BigInteger(133)).build())
 }
```

Normally, you'd order the parameters the other way around, but since the fluxes are so verbose I find this better readable.

--
EDIT:

I missed that you are trying to stub that same object that you are testing, this can only be done with [partial mocking](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#PartialMocks) and often indicates, that the code should be refactored. So replace `Mock`/`Stub` with `Spy` for partial mocking.

Comment: Thanks Leonard for looking into this. I am getting this error in the option1 you suggested......

Too few invocations for:

1 * recordCount.query(_) >> Flux.empty()   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

1 * recordCount.countRecords(2021-01-17T10:21:29.140140Z, 2021-01-17T10:31:29.140140Z)

Comment: @NishitJain I've updated the answer and the code.

Answer (score 0):

What about this way when you override the `query` method to return an expected `Flux`. In this case I would recommend to have 2 tests:

```
def "record count when empty Flux"() {
        given:
        def now = Instant.now()
        def last10Minutes = now.minus(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        def recordCount = new QueryDatabase() {
          @Overriden
          public Flux<CountRecord> query(String query) {
            Flux.empty()
          }
        }

        expect:
        recordCount.countRecords(last10Minutes, now) == 0
 }

def "record count when non empty Flux"() {
        given:
        def now = Instant.now()
        def last10Minutes = now.minus(10, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        def recordCount = new QueryDatabase() {
          @Overriden
          public Flux<CountRecord> query(String query) {
            Flux.just(CountRecord.builder().value(new BigInteger(133)).build())
          }
        }

        expect:
        recordCount.countRecords(last10Minutes, now) == 133
 }
```